# jQuery add class to button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simply add a class to a button using jQuery. But nothing happens. Why?

http://jsbin.com/makoxibogeje/2/edit

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Press me!</p>
    <button>Test</button>
    <button>Fiddle</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.spinner { color:red;}
```

Javascript

```
var B = {

    btn: $("button"),

    addSpinner: function() {
        B.btn.click(function() {
            this.addClass('spinner');
        });
    },
}
```

Comment: `this` is a simple DOM element - `$(this)` is the jQuery element which has the method `addClass`

Answer (score 5):

Inside that `click` callback function, `this` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Wrapping it as `$(this)` should make the `addClass` work.

```
var B = {

    btn: $("button"),

    addSpinner: function() {
        B.btn.click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('spinner');
        });
    },
}
```

P.S. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/snbn51os/) to demonstrate it working. Note that you also have to call `B.addSpinner();` from somewhere in order to wire up the click event handlers.

Comment: Troy is there a way to write the function like an IIFE? So I don't have to call it from anywhere? Or have it that if I have more functions in B I don't have to call them individually?

Comment: Here's a rather contrived example of B as a named IIFE, with another function added, and multiple instances (otherwise why make it a named function?): http://jsfiddle.net/troygizzi/zwtvqnnx/

Answer (score 1):

While the right answer is already given by `Troy Gizzy` but still you can improve a little by replaceing the `B` in `B.btn.click` with `this`, just like this

```js
var B = {
    btn: $("button"),
    addSpinner: function() {
        this.btn.click(function() { // <-- You've used B.btn.click
            $(this).addClass('spinner'); //<-- You had to use $(this) instead of this
        });
    },
}.addSpinner();
```

```css
.spinner { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <p>Press me!</p>
    <button>Test</button>
    <button>Fiddle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Is there a way to write the function like an IIFE? So I don't have to call it from anywhere? Or have it that if I have more functions in B I don't have to call them individually?

Comment: Welcome @MMRibot, In my example, I've called the method/function directly.

Comment: thanks, I see that, but how would I do that if I add more functions into my object?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the `this` variable with jQuery before calling the `addClass` function

```
var B = {

    btn: $("button"),

    addSpinner: function() {
        B.btn.click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('spinner'); // <----
        });
    },
}
```